# React Native Flatlist - VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flat list with large content and when I am scrolling down after 10 - 15  pages  on debugger console i have getting this:

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make
>   sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React
>   performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate,
>   etc. {dt: 582, prevDt: 1651, contentLength: 15187.5}

FYI: I have tried to use PureComponent and more ways but no one is helpful I am getting the same output in console.

Why I am getting this and how can solve this?

This is my code :

```
<FlatList
    data={outfits}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    numColumns={2}
    initialNumToRender={5}
    getItemLayout={(outfits, index) => (
       { length: 50, offset: 50 * index, index }
    )}
    extraData={this.state.extraData}
    renderItem={({item,index}) => <Items item={item} index={index}/>}
    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
    onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
    onEndReachedThreshold={20}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
/>
```

Comment: How did you implement your ```PureComponent```? Just in case you haven't tried yet, I'd suggest creating something like ListItem.js which renders your ```<Item item={item} index={index} />``` and exports ```PureComponent``` like this: ```export default class ListItem extends PureComponent```. In your ```FlatList``` file you import ListItem and use it like ```renderItem={(item, index) => <ListItem item={item} index={index} />} ```. If you have tried it already and didn't solve, let me know and I'll try to be more helpful

Comment: Item component is PureComponent in separate file 
`<Item item={item} index={index} />`

Comment: @soutot i have tried that way but it's not helped,please can you suggest another way?

Comment: I made some research and found this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13413#issuecomment-328256282 can you try, please? If it solves I'll add the solution to the answer

Comment: I have tried but it's not solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `Content` in https://docs.nativebase.io and I changed `Content` to `View` and used `PureComponent`. And now it's work!

Answer (score 1):

please use  RefreshControl  and props refresh control in Content native base

```
 import { StyleSheet, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';

...
render(
  <Content refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)} />}>
       <List .../>
      </Content>
...
)
```